# Finding Records by Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My first problem is that im not quiet sure if this could work at all. But since i've already got a lot of help here i'll at least try to ask something myself.

What i have here is a model 'thesis', which has_many 'tasks' through a relation model and also has_many 'checked_tasks'. Now i want to have only those theses where the number of tasks euqals the number of checked_tasks.

```
class Thesis < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :through => :relations
  has_many :checkedtasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :relation
end

class CheckedTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thesis
end
```

My first idea was simply to to a Thesis.where(*self*.tasks.count == *self*.checked_tasks.count) - but i coudn't figure out what to use instead of the *self* to get it working.

After that, i tried to do it whit scopes, but that still leaves me with the same problem.

After all, i'm not sure if there is a 'rails way' to do that - if so, i'd be very thankful for some help

Comment: A `CheckedTask` is a task that's been marked as complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
Thesis.joins(:checked_tasks, :tasks).group("thesis.id").select("thesis.*, count(distinct tasks.id) as task_count, count(distinct checked_tasks.id) as checked_count").having("checked_count = task_count")
```

But this is quite a pig of a query to run. it really feels like you should be redesigning your data model along the lines suggested by some of the commenters, using the join model between thesis and task to store the checkness of a task for a thesis.

Comment: okay. i thought it would be a better solution to select them that way than adding an extra boolean flag in the data model, but if all of you say i the other way that also works for me. anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: so i guess what you all are saying is that it is not possible to access the record itself whithin the where-clause like i wanted to do it in the first place?

Comment: The query I posted should be equivalent to what you're attempting, it's just rather gnarly

Answer (score 1):

A `CheckedTask` is simply a task that's been marked as complete? If that's so, I don't know why you need a separate class for it. A task is a task, and it's either complete or not complete. Track this state in a

You should be able to do this with a `scope` on the `Task` model, something like:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :checked, lambda { where(:complete => true) }

  ...
end
```

and make sure there's a `boolean` column on the `tasks` table called `complete` - it should be `false` if the task is not yet complete, and `true` if the task is complete.

To get the list of checked off tasks for a `Thesis`:

```
@thesis = Thesis.all.fist  # <= the first Thesis in the DB
@thesis.tasks.checked      # <= a collection of Task objects that have been checked
```

Comment: Actually, there is some more stuff behind it. I just thought it might be easier to understand that way. The tasks themselves can be used for different types of theses. therefore, the tasks  can not just have a boolean flag because they are used for many theses...

Comment: So then what is the purpose of a `Task` vs. a `CheckedTask`? What concepts to they represent in your application?

Comment: Every thesis has a set of **tasks** which have to be completed before the thesis itsself is complete. Also, every thesis has a **type**, thorugh which the tasks for a thesis are defined. this association is set in the table **relations**.

Comment: after all, in the table **checked_tasks** i have the id of the thesis and the id of the relation. thats how all fits together.

Comment: Then can you add the boolean to the `Relations` join model? One of the benefits of `:through` is that you can add attributes on the relation itself.

Comment: No, sadly i can't since every relation is used for many theses.